IFormFile Bind By a Object List
public class SalesInvoiceViewModel
    {
        public int? salesInvoiceId { get; set; }
        public string salesInvoiceNo { get; set; }
        public int? salesOrderId { get; set; }
        public string salesOrderNo { get; set; }
        public DateTime? salesInvoiceDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? paymentDate { get; set; }
        public int? partyId { get; set; }
        public int? storeId { get; set; }
        public string mobileNo { get; set; }
        public string alternateMobileNo { get; set; }
        public string address { get; set; }
        public decimal? totalGross { get; set; }
        public decimal? totalVat { get; set; }
        public decimal? totalAit { get; set; }
        public decimal? shippingCost { get; set; }
        public decimal? totalDiscountAmount { get; set; }
        public decimal? grandTotal { get; set; }
        public string approvalStatus { get; set; } //0='Pending', 1='Approve', 2='Rejected/Cancelled', 3='Shipped', 4='Received', 5='OnHold', 6='Refund'
        public bool? isActive { get; set; }
        public bool? isSelect { get; set; }
        public string refNo { get; set; }
        public string remarks { get; set; }
        public int? transactionTypeId { get; set; }
        public string flyingCustomer { get; set; }
        public List<SalesInvoiceViewModel> lstMasterViewModel { get; set; } = new List<SalesInvoiceViewModel>();
        public List<SalesInvoiceDetailsViewModel> lstDetailsViewModel { get; set; } = new List<SalesInvoiceDetailsViewModel>();
        public List<SalesInvoiceTandCViewModel> tcLstDetailsViewModel { get; set; } = new List<SalesInvoiceTandCViewModel>();
    }

 public class SalesInvoiceDetailsViewModel
    {
        public int? salesInvDetailsId { get; set; }
        public int? salesInvoiceId { get; set; }
        public int? productId { get; set; }
        public int? productWiseSpecificationId { get; set; }
        public decimal? invoiceQty { get; set; }
        public decimal? convertionQty { get; set; }
        public decimal? CtnQty { get; set; }
        public int? toUomId { get; set; }
        public decimal? price { get; set; }
        public decimal? vat { get; set; }
        public decimal? ait { get; set; }
        public decimal? discountAmount { get; set; }
        public decimal? Total { get; set; }
        public bool? isActive { get; set; }
        public bool? isSelect { get; set; }
        public int? barcodeId { get; set; }
        public string serialNo { get; set; }
        public int? salesOrderId { get; set; }
        public int? SalOrderDetailId { get; set; }
        public string attachmentPath { get; set; }
        public string attachments { get; set; }
        public IFormFile ImageFile { get; set; }
        //public List<IFormFile> ImageFile { get; set; } = new List<IFormFile>();

    }

Here I have ImageFile property in SalesInvoiceDetailsViewModel.
I send Request by PostMan like this way
Postman Request Parameter
But it not fire my controller. when I remove  public IFormFile ImageFile { get; set; } then it work nicely.
In that case how can I send IFormFile By [FromForm] anotation

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
